# Remote login to hootsuite via cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to remotely login to Hootsuite using cURL.  I want to have the Hootsuite app showing in an iframe within my own application.  I am using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.  I just get presented with the login page, but with no error re: login.

```
$username="xxx"; 
$password="yyy"; 
$url="https://hootsuite.com/login"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "loginInfo[email]=".$username."&loginInfo[password]=".$password; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;    rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: it probably checks for some of the hidden fields in the form too.

Comment: Do you actually need cURL, or can you simply include https://hootsuite.com/whatever in an iframe?

Comment: I would suggest you use something like the Network tab in Firebug to see exactly what cookies and POST fields are sent when you log in using your browser.

Comment: Yes I want the user to be auto logged in, so they don't have to worry about logging into Hootsuite within my app.  I will try to see if there are hidden fields to POST as well.

Comment: No go on the hidden post fields.  I added them and I now get an error about invalid username / password, but still can't login.